# Let $|x|\leq1, |y|\leq 1$. Show that$0 \leq x^{2}+y^{2} -2x^{2} y^{2}+2xy \sqrt{1-x^{2}} \sqrt{1-y^{2}} \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Let $|x|\leq1, |y|\leq 1$. Show that

$$
0  \leq x^{2}+y^{2} -2x^{2} y^{2}+2xy  \sqrt{1-x^{2}}  \sqrt{1-y^{2}} \leq 1
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

With $x = \sin a$, $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos a$ and similarly for
$y = \sin b \ldots$ the expression becomes $\sin^2(a+b)$.

Answer (score 2):

take $a=\sqrt{y^2(1-x^{2})}$$b=  \sqrt{x^2(1-y^{2})}$

and Use $(a+b)^2=a^2=b^2+2ab$ to show  inequality

Comment: try the subharmonic concept to prove that the max value is on the boundary

Answer (score 2):

We need only note that
\begin{align*}
x^{2}+y^{2} -2x^{2} y^{2}+2xy  \sqrt{1-x^{2}}  \sqrt{1-y^{2}} &= \left(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\right)^2\\
&\le \left(\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(2-x^2-y^2)}\,\right)^2\\
&\le \left(\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2 + 2-x^2-y^2)\,\right)^2\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Worth mentioning that in the first inequality you used Cauchy-Schwarz and in the second you used AM-GM.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that for $|x|\le 1,|y|\le 1$, $$\arccos x +\arccos y =\arccos \left(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)  $$ or $$\cos \left(\arccos x +\arccos y \right) = \left(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)  $$ and hence we can say 
$$-1 \le \left(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right) \le 1$$

Then the given expression becomes
$$0 \leq (x+y)^2 \leq x^{2}+y^{2} -2x^{2} y^{2}+2xy  \sqrt{1-x^{2}}  \sqrt{1-y^{2}} \leq (x-y)^2 \leq 1$$